Are the usages of "elsewhere" and "somewhere else" completely the same?
Are the usages of "elsewhere" and "somewhere else" completely the same?
Could native speakers please explain it to me? Thank you.

They mean the same, but 'elsewhere' may be considered to be more 'formal' or 'literary', and more suited to written English.

One difference is that you can say "France and elsewhere" potentially meaning "France and (several) other places", but "France and somewhere else" would mean "France and one other place". I think "somewhere else" is more likely to mean "a single place" than "elsewhere" is.

But it's kind of a vague question. I'm sure there are multiple specific cases where they have slightly different meanings or only one is appropriate, but generally they mean the same thing.

@StuartF I think that example would make a good answer.
